# How to generate image noise frequency?

Tags: c, image-processing, frequency, noise-generator

I read the very interesting and informative article on image noise located here:
http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-noise-2.htm

One of the key points is **noise frequency** which can be high or low. I was curious as to how this would be calculated?

I came across another article in which the developer achieved low frequency iage noise by sampling the surrounding pixels and then performing an average. But this requires a separate calculation pass after all the noise has been calculated.

Is this how it's traditionally done or is there a different way to calculate image noise frequency?

Thanks

Comment: Very useful link that I hadn't seen before, thanks. They're wrong about one thing though - the reason noise is more visible in dark areas is due to the gamma function, not SNR.

Answer (score 1):

Look up Perlin noise.

"Salt and pepper noise" is white or black pixels scattered at random over the source. It's a fairly common sort of noise, but not useful for much visually. It has the highest frequency that the image sampling supports.

Perlin noise consists of noise of several frequencies, or "octaves" superimposed on each other. It is useful, with various parameters it looks like wood, or clouds, or swirling lava. It can also be used a bit more subtly to give slightly rugged effects to non-smooth surfaces.

The frequency is simply the distance in pixels at which existence of noise at one pixel bears no relation to the noise at the other pixel (for non-repeating noise) or the "repeat length" for repeating noise.

Comment: Hi Malcolm - thanks for your reply. I'm familiar with Perlin Noise and you're absolutely right that it features frequency. However, I am interested in this from a camera image noise standpoint and the noise models used in that type of noise is gaussian, Lorentz and Poisson distribution, not really perlin type noise. How does one apply frequency to these types of noise models? Is it possible?

Comment: The normal model of gaussian noise is that it is pixel independent, thus of infinite frequency, and with an error of +/- 3 * sigma at each pixel, with a bell curve peak at 0. sigma is the free parameter. However there will be a type where the noise is not spatially independent.